# Replace Json.Nets Standard Serialization Dictionary with Custom Dictionary globally

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Json.Net uses the default .Net Dictionary for Serialization of JSON Dictionaries when i just use the IDictionary interface. I want to replace it against my Custom Version of a Dictionary globally.
Do I need to write a JsonConverter in order to do this or do i just miss a Setting like:

```
config.DefaultDictType = typeof(MyDict);
```

somewhere

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple setting for this.  Properties declared as `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` [are allocated as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if the current value is null](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonDictionaryContract.cs).

However, if you pre-allocate the custom dictionaries in the default constructors for your classes, Json.NET will use the pre-existing allocated dictionary rather than allocating a new one.   (This is why [`JsonConverter.ReadJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) has an `existingValue` argument.)

For instance:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
}

public class DictionaryContainer
{
    public DictionaryContainer()
    {
        this.Values = new MyDictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var container = new DictionaryContainer();
        container.Values["one"] = "first";
        container.Values["two"] = "second";
        container.Values["three"] = "third";

        Debug.Assert(container.Values.GetType() == typeof(MyDictionary<string, string>)); // No assert

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container, Formatting.Indented);

        var container2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DictionaryContainer>(json);

        Debug.Assert(container.Values.GetType() == container2.Values.GetType());// No assert
    }
}
```

If this is impractical (because of, e.g., issues with legacy code), the easiest way to achieve what you want is probably with a single global converter that, when reading, allocates dictionaries for *all* properties defined to return type `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` for any key and value:

```
public abstract class CustomDictionaryTypeReaderBase : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract Type CreateDictionaryType(Type tKey, Type tValue);

    bool GetIDictionaryGenericParameters(Type objectType, out Type tKey, out Type tValue)
    {
        tKey = tValue = null;
        if (!objectType.IsGenericType)
            return false;
        var genericType = objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (genericType != typeof(IDictionary<,>))
            return false;
        var args = objectType.GetGenericArguments();
        if (args.Length != 2)
            tKey = tValue = null;
        tKey = args[0];
        tValue = args[1];
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Type tKey, tValue;
        return GetIDictionaryGenericParameters(objectType, out tKey, out tValue);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (existingValue != null)
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
            return existingValue;
        }
        else
        {
            Type tKey, tValue;
            bool ok = GetIDictionaryGenericParameters(objectType, out tKey, out tValue);
            if (!ok)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            }
            else
            {
                var realType = CreateDictionaryType(tKey, tValue);
                Debug.Assert(objectType.IsAssignableFrom(realType));
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, realType);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class MyCustomDictionaryTypeReader : CustomDictionaryTypeReaderBase
{
    protected override Type CreateDictionaryType(Type tKey, Type tValue)
    {
        var dictType = typeof(MyDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] { tKey, tValue });
        return dictType;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters = new[] { new MyCustomDictionaryTypeReader() };

        var multiContainer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleDictionaryContainer>(json2, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve what you wanted is by modifying the `DefaultContractResolver`, override its `CreateDictionaryContract()` method, and then set it as the serializer's **default** `ContractResolver`.

Assuming your custom dictionary is defined as:

```
public class CustomDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{        
  public string Custom { get { return "I'm Custom"; } }
}
```

You could implement the custom contract resolver as:

```
public class CustomDictionaryContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
  public CustomDictionaryContractResolver() : base(true) { }      

  protected override JsonDictionaryContract CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
  {
    // let the base class do the heavy lifting
    var contract = base.CreateDictionaryContract(objectType);

    // nothing todo if the created type is already our custom dictionary type
    if (IsGenericDefinition(contract.CreatedType, typeof (CustomDictionary<,>)))
      return contract;

    if (IsGenericDefinition(contract.UnderlyingType, typeof(IDictionary<,>)) || (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(contract.UnderlyingType)))
    {        
      contract.CreatedType = typeof(CustomDictionary<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(contract.DictionaryKeyType ?? typeof(object), contract.DictionaryValueType ?? typeof(object));

      // Set our object instantiation using the default constructor;
      // You need to modify this, if your custom dictionary does not 
      // have a default constructor.
      contract.DefaultCreator = () => Activator.CreateInstance(contract.CreatedType);              
    }

    return contract;
  }

  static bool IsGenericDefinition(Type type, Type genericDefinition)
  {
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericDefinition;
  }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomDictionaryContractResolver()
};
```

For example:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    const string json = @"{""FirstName"": ""John"",""LastName"": ""Smith"",""Properties"": {""Email"": ""john.smith@example.com"",""Level"": 42,""Admin"": true}}";

    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
      ContractResolver = new CustomDictionaryContractResolver()
    };

    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);

    Debug.WriteLineIf(myObject.FirstName == "John", "FirstName is John");
    Debug.WriteLineIf(myObject.LastName == "Smith", "LastName is Smith");
    Debug.WriteLineIf(myObject.Properties != null, "Properties is not NULL");
    Debug.WriteLineIf(myObject.Properties.Count == 3, "Properties has 3 items");
    Debug.WriteLineIf(myObject.Properties.GetType() == typeof(CustomDictionary<string, object>), "Properties is CustomDictionary<,>");

    var customDictionary = myObject.Properties as CustomDictionary<string, object>;
    Debug.WriteLineIf(customDictionary != null, "Properties say " + customDictionary.Custom);
  }
}
```

If you run the `TestClass.Test()` method, you should see the following in the *Output*:

```
    FirstName is John
    LastName is Smith
    Properties is not NULL
    Properties has 3 items
    Properties is CustomDictionary
    Properties say I'm Custom
```